# Using Field value in a Parameter DefaultValueExpression

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have to use *JasperReports* but i'm struggling with getting the data out.
Here is my Java side declaration:

```
Map<String, List<TransactionBean>> shCredits = new HashMap<String, List<TransactionBean>>();
```

In the declared *HashMap*, I store clients, who have transactions.

I passed this *HashMap* to the report for listing the transactions group by clients.

Here is the *JR* side:

```
<parameter name="shareHolderCreditBeans" class="java.util.HashMap">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("shCreditBeans")]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="credits" class="java.util.List">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{shareHolderCreditBeans}.get("12")]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
...
<field name="clientId" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[clientId]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

My problem is that if I use hardcoded key ("12") in 'credits' parameter, i can get the client transaction list. I'm also able to use the *clientId* field in a *textField*, but not as a key like:

```
$P{shareHolderCreditBeans}.get($F{clientId})
```

If i do this it returns with null.

Is it the right way, using field as parameter key?

Please let me know if I am not clear enough about describing this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I could resolve it with casting:

```
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource((java.util.List)($P{shareHolderCreditBeans}.get($F{clientId})))]]></dataSourceExpression>
```